# npm install gives npm ERR

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

PS E:\Nice\Ok\hashlips_art_engine-main> npm install

npm WARN old lockfile

npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old
version of npm,

npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.

npm WARN old lockfile

npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...

npm WARN old lockfile

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path E:\Nice\Ok\hashlips_art_engine-main\node_modules

npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
'E:\Crypto\NFTS\hashlips_art_engine-main\node_modules'

npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
'E:\Crypto\NFTS\hashlips_art_engine-main\node_modules'] {

npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',

npm ERR!   path: 'E:\Nice\Ok\hashlips_art_engine-main\node_modules'

npm ERR!

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),

npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\AMD\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-30T17_46_27_316Z-debug.log

It seem to keep getting this problem, I have search for solutions but nothing worked. Please Help me Out!

Comment: "The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of", delete it and npm install again

Comment: The problem isn’t the lock file it is that it can’t create E:\Nice\Ok\hashlips_art_engine-main\node_modules - does your user have permissions to that folder?

Comment: Just delete the `node_modules` folders & `package-lock.json` and re-install using `npm install`. It should fix this error.